# How to get Network Info - Android

Tags: java, android, deprecation-warning, android-connectivitymanager, networkinfo

This is my code below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("BooleanMethodIsAlwaysInverted")
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

When I run the above code, I am getting a `Deprecated` warning saying that `getActiveNetworkInfo` and `isConnected` methods are deprecated.

I don't want to continue this code for any longer. What are some of the alternatives of the above code?

Can someone please help me? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my code which I use in my application to check if device is connected to network. It does not contain any deprecated code as of now.

> **Kotlin**

```
private fun isInternetAvailable(): Boolean {
    var result = false
    val connectivityManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
    connectivityManager?.let {
        it.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)?.apply {
            result = when {
                hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

> **Java**

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
    boolean result = false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
        if (networkCapabilities != null) {
            if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                result = true;
            } else if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                result = true;
            } else {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Read more about Connectivity Manager and Network Capabilities [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities(android.net.Network))

Comment: Thank you a lot....you might have solved my problem, but could you give me the above code in Java?

Comment: With the java code, you have solved my problem. Thanks!!!